# Rewrite url using .htaccess in PHP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have tried below .htaccess code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1[L]
```

for rewrite url

```
localhost/example/page.php?name=about-us
```

to

```
localhost/example/about-us
```

this .htaccess working fine but in some cases i don't want to rewrite the url.
In below cases

```
localhost/example/index.php
localhost/example/
localhost/example/sitemap.php
```

I don't want url rewriting.
how can I do it ?

Comment: Take a look at the `RewriteCond` command, it allows to implement exceptions or conditions: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond You will find _endless_ examples in the documentation I referenced, on google and here on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rule  needs a condition to keep off matching your orignal files and dirs.

Try :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1[L]
```